# I want to make a datatable responsive to zooming, but it disappears with solutions that I've looked

Tags: javascript, html, datatable

I'm trying to get these table ("tablaRealizaPagos") to not overflow from this modal. 
The desired effect is that the user to be able to zoom in or out and the table should show fully, or at least capable of scrolling to the side.

[image]

This is the code I'm using:

```
<div id="helperDpModalPagosLicitaciones" class="modal fade" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static"
     data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-full">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Registrar Pagos</h4>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label id="idLicitacionPagos"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group panel panel-body col-sm-12" style="margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:20px;">
                <div class="row form-group col-xs-12">
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <h6>Realizar Pagos</h6>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <table id="tablaRealizaPagos" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Cuotas</th>
                            <th>% Pago</th>
                            <th>Monto a pagar</th>
                            <th>Descripción</th>
                            <th>Saldo</th>
                            <th>Fecha de pago</th>
                            <th>Monto Definito</th>
                            <th>Fecha de pago Programada</th>
                            <th>Acción</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-12"  style="margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:20px;">

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <label id="idlicitacionHelperPagoLabel">Monto Adjudicado</label>
                    <input type="text" id="idlicitacionMontoAdjudicadoPago" class="form-control" style="text-transform:uppercase" maxlength="100" disabled />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <label id="idlicitacionHelperPagoLabel">Suma Pagos</label>
                    <input type="text" id="idlicitacionMontosPagados" class="form-control" style="text-transform:uppercase" maxlength="100" disabled />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <label id="idlicitacionHelperPagoLabel">Alertas</label>
                    <input type="text" id="idlicitacionAlertaSobrepasoPago" class="form-control" style="text-transform:uppercase;color:red"  maxlength="100" disabled />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12" id="DivHideButtomsPay" >

                <div class="col-sm-6">

                    <button id="helperBotonFinalizarLicitacion" type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="width:100%;" width="100%"   onclick="fnCambioEstado(1,0);">Terminar Licitación (Licitación Finalizada)</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <button id="helperBotonRecepcionProvLicitacion" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" style="width:100%;" width="100%" onclick="fnCambioEstado(2,0);">Recepción Provisoría (Aún en Garantía) </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="col-sm-12">

            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">


                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <button id="helperDpBtnCancelarPago" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="helperDpCancelarPagos();">Cerrar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the js to define it:

```
 $('#tablaRealizaPagos').dataTable({
            data: helperDpArraySolicitudes,
            columns: [

                { title: "N° Factura" },
                { title: "% Pago" },
                { title: "Monto a pagar" },
                { title: "Descripción" },
                { title: "Saldo" },
                { title: "Fecha de pago" },
                { title: "Monto Programado" },
                { title: "Fecha de pago Programada" },
                { title: "Acción" }
            ], columnDefs: [
                { width: '10%', targets: 0 },
                { width: '5%', targets: 1 },
                { width: '15%', targets: 2 },
                { width: '5%', targets: 3 },
                { width: '10%', targets: 4 },
                { width: '15%', targets: 5 },
                { width: '15%', targets: 6 },
                { width: '10%', targets: 7 },
                { width: '15%', targets: 8 }


            ],
            "autoWidth": false,
            "pageLength": 10
        });
```

I have looked everywhere but somehow, I can't get it to work... Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Try scrollX - Though your dataTables library is different than the version I'm using.

```
$('#tablaRealizaPagos').dataTable( {
        "scrollX": true
...
    } );
```

And probably a CSS overflow property on your popup.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

or maybe a maxWidth on your dialog

```
var wWidth = $(window).width();
var wHeight = $(window).height();
var dWidth = wWidth * 0.9; // 90% of screen width
var dHeight = wHeight * 0.95; // 95% of screen height
```

Comment: You may also want to update your Datatables library: https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-types/jqueryui-modal.html